# Why my code raises an error when trying to create and populate an excel file with some data?

Tags: python, python-3.x, excel, pandas, xlsxwriter

My python code was running without any issue. it creates a new excel file and stores some data in it.
I removed Microsoft office from my machine and then install it again. Then the problem arises.

FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'XXX.xlsx'

I tried my code in another machine and it is working fine. It seems the issue is on xlsxwriter, although it is installed and already updated.

```
    fname= 'stats.xlsx'
    # Save worksheets into the workbook
    writer = pd.ExcelWriter(fname, engine='xlsxwriter')
    df1.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Results')
    df2.to_excel(writer, sheet_name='Config')
    writer.save()
```

[image]

Comment: When creating a file that error usually means you are trying to write to a directory that doesn't exist.

Comment: Try `fname= 'stats.xlsx'`

Comment: Thank you. before it was working fine, how now directory not exist. for file name with xlsx it is already with xlsx

Comment: Can you add the full error traceback to your question.

Comment: Thanks, i added the full error traceback

Comment: Does anyone know how to solve this?